# Derive a power series expansion about $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$(1+x)^2y''(x) - xy'(x) + y(x) = e^{-x} $

If possible, derive a power series expansion about $x=0$ up to the first 3 terms.

State which parts are the particular solution and which parts are the general solution.

My attempt:

I believe that we are looking for an ordinary point for this ODE because the coefficients for $y'(x)$ and $y(x)$ are analytic. However I don't know how to work with sums. How would I proceed from this?

Comment: That looks like a homework exercise. You seem to have forgotten to _ask a question about it_, though (Note that "please do my homework for me" is not a question).

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand?

Comment: This is a site for asking and answering questions. You have not asked any question, merely typed in a homework problem.

Comment: Sorry, I will fix this.

Comment: See [How to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that $$y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$ Calculate the first and 2nd derivatives, express $e^{-x}$ also as a power series. Plug them all into the equation. Make use of this identity:

if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n = 0$, then $b_n = 0$ for all $n$.